# Cambiar diagonal invertida \ por diagonal / en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una path de recibo de mi base de datos pero es un path de directorio de archivos de windows es decir que tiene la siguiente estructura.

```
\\C:\Archivos\Otros\Etc\Etc
```

Utilizando la function replace de Javascript estoy tratando de reemplazar la diagonal invertida por la diagonal normal.

```
cadena.replace("\","/");
```

El problema es que javascript detecta la diagonal invertida como un salto de linea y no logro conseguir lo tome como un caracter, podrian ayudarme con esto.

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero que nada, el caracter \ es un caracter para escapar signos, por lo que deberás escaparlo a sí mismo, pues si pones \", lo que haces es considerar a la comilla como parte del string haciendo que no se cierre.

Ahora bien, el prototipo `replace`, solo reemplaza la primera coincidencia, podrías usar [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), pero no es soportado por Internet Explorer, así que podrías usar una expresión regular.

```js
let cadena = "\\\\C:\Archivos\\Otros\\Etc\\Etc";
// Acá escapé la diagonal invertida, para que conforme parte del string
// Si recibes el string desde una petición o input, este ya vendrá escapado
cadena = cadena.replace(/\\/g, "/");
console.log(cadena);
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que al poner \" Javascript interpreta que estás escapando las comillas, por tanto tienes que escapar la barra invertida.
Intenta esto
cadena.replaceAll("\\","/")

Supongo que quieres cambiar todas las barras invertidas, por eso pongo replaceAll